# Is there a quick way to rebuild spell files from wordlists?

Tags: vim

Is there any way to tell vim to update spell files for all languages listed in `'spelllang'` to pick up wordlist changes from outside of vim?

I've started checking a wordlist file into git since I'm tired of adding the same words on multiple computers. I don't want to add the spell file to the git repo since merges would be ugly every time, but whenever I open vim, any recent updates are ignored until I do something from inside vim that rebuilds the spell file, such as `zg` to add a word to the dictionary.

Answer (score 15):

I've solved this by adding the *.spl to the .gitignore file and then in the vimrc (which is also synced with GIT, add:

```
for d in glob('~/.vim/spell/*.add', 1, 1)
    if filereadable(d) && (!filereadable(d . '.spl') || getftime(d) > getftime(d . '.spl'))
        exec 'mkspell! ' . fnameescape(d)
    endif
endfor
```

source: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5050/how-to-share-vim-spellchecking-additions-between-multiple-machines

This will cause vim to rebuild the .spl file each time the .add file has been updated when vim is started.

Answer (score 3):

If you only have a single spell file, just put this in your `.vimrc`:

```
exec 'silent mkspell! ' . &spellfile . '.spl'
```

Comment: I had to write this instead:

`exec 'silent mkspell! ' . &spellfile . '.spl ' . &spellfile`

The command is `mkspell {outname} {inname}`. On my system with your command it created a spelldb called `en.local.utf-8.add.spl.utf-8.spl` with that extra extension `utf-8.spl` instead of just `en.local.utf-8.add.spl`.

Answer (score 3):

I've created a [Vim plugin](https://github.com/micarmst/vim-spellsync) for this. It finds the path to the spell folders automatically and then calls `mkspell` on any word lists it finds at startup to regenerate the spell files.  It also creates `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes` files in the spell directories to exclude binary spell files and to use Git's [union merge driver](https://web.archive.org/web/20181009034917/https://krlmlr.github.io/using-gitattributes-to-avoid-merge-conflicts/) to avoid conflicts when merging spell files from two different machines. Thanks to [Sato Katsura](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5052/19028) for the `mkspell` example.

https://github.com/micarmst/vim-spellsync

Comment: Just following up to say I finally got around to installing and trying this (5 years later) and I'm a fan. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can create git smudge/clean filters and post-checkout hook to call `:mkspell`.

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.vim/spell
$ cd ~/.vim/spell
$ git init
$ echo '*.spl' > .gitignore
$ touch words.utf-8.add
$ git add . && git commit -m 'init'
$ echo '*.add filter=spellfile' > .git/info/attributes
$ git config filter.spellfile.smudge cat
$ git config filter.spellfile.clean 'sort -u'
$ cd .git/hooks/
$ vim mkspell
```

```bash
#!/bin/sh
SPELL_FILE="`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`/words.utf-8.add" \
    vim -i NONE -u NORC -U NONE -V1 -nNesc '
        execute ":mkspell! " . fnameescape($SPELL_FILE) | echo "" | qall!
        '
```

```
$ chmod +x ./mkspell
$ ln -s ./mkspell post-checkout
```

Then add `spellfile` setting into your `~/.vimrc`

```
set spellfile=~/.vim/spell/words.utf-8.add
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with a git repo of a dictionary makes sense. The problem is with informing `vim` about your dictionary. A simple solution is with mapping vim to use the right dictionary. For Instance, if your words are in `my-dictionary.txt` then you can run from vim:

```
:mkspell ~/.vim/spell/en_my_dict /path/to/git/repo/my-dictionary.txt
```

I probably use something like:

```
" Set up Dictionary for check
" This is will add your dictionary to existing list.
" To use only your dictionary use, setlocal &spelllang=en_my_dict
nmap <leader>ss :setlocal &spelllang=join(add(split(&spelllang, ','), 'en_my_dict'), ',')

" Spell Check (Redo to disable)
nmap <silent> <leader>sc :set spell!<CR>
```

Comment: I already have the spell files set up the way I want (it's configured in my vimrc to use a spelllang corresponding to a wordlist in ~/.vim/spell/, symlinked to a file in a git working dir). The problem is just that whenever that file changes from outside vim, vim keeps using the stale .spl file instead of the newer wordlist.